# Why does my PowerShell script prompt for permission to add items to arrays?

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script with the following excerpt:

```
foreach ($pc in $ComputerName) {
  $appnames = $appnames | Sort-Object
  Write-Debug "Number of entries in `$appnames = $($appnames.count)"
  if ($AsHTML) {#Switch Parameter
    Write-Verbose "Generating HTML Report..."
    $th = "<TR><TH>Application Name</TH>" #Create Top header
    foreach ($pc in $ComputerName) {
       $th += "<TH>$pc</TH>" #Another header for each pc
    }
    $th += "</TR>" #Header finished
    $rows = ""
    foreach ($app in $appnames) {
      $rows += "<TR><TH>$app</TH>"
      foreach ($pc in $ComputerName) {
        Write-Debug $RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app]
        $currentApp = $RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app]
        if ($currentApp) {
          if ($currentApp.DisplayVersion) {
            $status = $currentApp.DisplayVersion
          } else {
            $status = "Version-nr. N/A"
          }
        } else {
          $status = "Application N/A"
        }
        $rows += "<TD>$status</TD>" #Intersection cell for each pc
      }
      $rows += "</TR>"
    }
    Write-Verbose "Finishing html report..."
    $html = "
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          body { background-color:#FFFFCC;
          font-family:Tahoma;
          font-size:12pt; }
          td, th { border:1px solid #000033;
          border-collapse:collapse; }
          th { color:white;
            background-color:#000033; }
          table, tr, td, th { padding: 0px; margin: 0px }
          table { margin-left:10px; }
        </style>
        <Title>Application versions Report</Title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          $th
          $rows
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>"
  }
}
```

So, to explain the wall of text above a bit;

- $RegistryEntries is a Hashtable of Hashtables, with the top-level keys being computer names,  and the low-level hashtable keys being application names found in the Uninstall part of the registry. The corresponding values to the Application-name-keys are custom PSObjects with three general properties: .Displayname, .DisplayVersion, and .UninstallString. (Not all objects have all of the three properties, but each object has at least one).
- What I hope to achieve with this HTML-table is to get some kind of "pivot-table" (ref. Wikipedia entry for Pivot Tables, but not quite), where I can get Application Names on the Y-axis, and computer names on the X-axis, and the Version number of said application on said computer where they intersect.

So again, with that in mind, could someone help me understand why my script when run prompts me in the shell for permission to add application names to the array $appnames (elsewhere in the script), as well as doing the same with the HTML input that is being put into $rows?

Another thing which is a bit on the side (maybe even off-topic), my $RegistryEntries object, the hashtable of hashtables, is for some reason not possible to access in the way I do it on the two following lines:

```
Write-Debug $RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app]
$currentApp = $RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app]
```

Would anyone be able to tell me why?

To sum up/TL;DR:

1. Why does my function when trying to add items to an array created inside the script prompt me for permission to do just this in the shell?
2. With the custom object I've described above holding the data I want to display in my HTML table, what am I doing wrong in trying to access it in the above code excerpt?

PS: The script works in the sense that if I sit throughout all the prompts I get in the shell, hitting A + Return all the time, I will get a HTML table of the kind that I want, but all the cells where an application name interstices a computername will say "Application N/A".

Comment: It's on SilentlyContinue. I guess that's the standard, I haven't touched it.

Comment: Hm, I was wondering because you mention prompts and `Write-Debug` and `Write-Verbose` can do so depending on `$*Preference`.

Comment: I just managed to recreate the prompt in the shell, and it happened _after_ I got `DEBUG: <Text I wrote with code in it>` 
AKA on the next line.
http://imgur.com/gje9R

Comment: That really points to either `$DebugPreference` or a `-Debug` parameter.

Comment: I did use -Debug switch at times while I was doing just that, debugging. I was not aware that this would prompt me each time the code passed the Debug statement. We learn something every day^^ Where could I read up on the effect of the `-Debug` switch? 
As in what to write in place of `*`in `Get-Help *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have your `$DebugPreference` and/or `VerbosePreference` set to `Inquire` which will prompt every time `Write-Debug` or `Write-Verbose` are called, respectively:

```
Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [H] Halt Command  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

You probably want to set them to `Continue` instead. Another source might be the `-Debug` switch.

Regarding your second question, it's a little long to explain, but for arguments to commands you have to put such expressions in parentheses:

```
Write-Debug ($RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app])
$currentApp = $RegistryEntries[$pc].Value[$app]
```

Comment: I think the answer I was looking for was being told/finding out that adding the `-Debug` switch to my cmdlets would make the whole function stop and wait for my go-ahead each time it hit a `Write-Debug` statement! But since you're the one who got me here, I thank you for providing the answer =). (I did have a `Write-Debug` each place I added into an array for obvious reasons, why I thought the array operation was to blame^^)

Comment: Such things are really difficult to spot if one cannot try out your code like you do ;)

Comment: Yeah, when I first wrote the question 8 hours ago, this was my first attempt at writing a question, so I thought that you might not be interested in reading my ugly code of 200 lines^^ If I see you around at a later time, be sure to say hi and you'll get a pastebin link! =D

Comment: Well, 200 lines are definitely too much, but the code where you see the problem would certainly be appreciated ;)

Comment: Oh you mean the prompt from the shell don't you, not the code? I'm getting confused by you saying "The code where you see the problem" since the problem came evidently to the shell, while it originated in my code (and ok, 200 was a bit of an exaggeration since it includes help-documentation and more, here is the link if you're interested: http://pastebin.com/tdVjntZ9 
And here is another link I think you might find interesting:
http://bit.ly/LRyH5b)